# My own class (List<int>) does not like to intersect. WHY?

Tags: c#, types, intersect

I have a class that is derived from List.
I am not able to use intersect() on instances of my class.
Why?

What I have is:

```
class myList : List<int>
{ ... }
```

What I try to do is

```
myList list1 = new some initialization...
myList list2 = new some initialization...

myList list3 = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

This doesn't work.
Compiler complains about something like 
"Error  1   Typ "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" cannot be converted implicitly into "myList"."

I do not understand what type of type confusion is going on here :(
I already tried some casts in my Intersect-example but it did not work.

Can anyone please explain me what's the problem here, and what I made wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions - so your class would be called `MyList` rather than `myList`, although even that is a poor name as it doesn't describe the purpose at all. Are you sure you need to extend `List<int>` in the first place? That's rarely a good idea, compared with using composition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method doesn't try to return a collection of the same kind as the inputs (e.g. a `List<int>`). It just returns a sequence implementing `IEnumerable<T>` for an appropriate `T`. So in your case you could use:

```
myList list1 = new some initialization...
myList list2 = new some initialization...

IEnumerable<int> list3 = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

If you want to create a `myList` with that content, you'll need to do so with something like:

```
myList list4 = new myList();
list4.AddRange(list3);
```

(Or if your class provides a constructor accepting an `IEnumerable<int>` parameter, that would work too.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this really cool answer. 1. everything works now. 2. I now fully understand the issue I had!  Thanks a lot!